# Creating Custom data type in umbraco 7.3 without using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to create a custom data type in Umbraco 7.3 without using AngularJS but I cannot do it because I don't have any knowledge about AngularJs.

I googled and saw that all of examples wrote by using AngularJs.

Is there any way to create a custom data type in Umbraco 7.3 without using Angular?

If not, please introduce some good sources to learning Angular that should be simple and practical.

Comment: Did any of my suggestions below work? What kind of data type are you trying to create? There are data types that merely extend other data types or allow a list of checkboxes, dropdown lists, radio buttons, etc (as per my answers below) or you can have a seriously complex data type that provides a UI for an API.

Comment: @ForTheWatch  After studying about creating custom data type, I have this problem, actually.Please visit 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/33509696/1817640

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't believe it is possible since the interface is all in Angular but I could be wrong. Certainly the method that the team would prefer us to use is the Angular method. I have to be honest it was a little bit of a leap for me too creating my first editor but it's really not that difficult, trust me.

There is a good thread in the Umbraco form here: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/46925-Custom-datatype-in-umbraco-701

And I would advise downloading the Umbraco source as the best examples are in the source itself.

Comment: I think you are right. I must learn AngularJs. 
What are benefits of Angular that Umbraco team has used it?

Comment: I did something after reading some documents about AngularJS.Now, I have a new question about it. Please look at that.
(Next comment is about it.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509696/sending-data-by-using-angularjs-to-an-action-method-of-asp-net-mvc-5-controller?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you can generate custom property editors using just C# classes and class attributes. Or you can extend existing data types and tweak them. The only problem is you're limited to lists and displaying existing JSON feeds - most of which is best done using extensions like [uComponents](http://ucomponents.org/) and [NuPickers](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers).

Have you viewed [Nibble's blog](http://www.nibble.be/?p=337)? He's the primary source for most things data type related.

For your situation, the nuPickers dot net extensions sounds best. There's examples on [this link](https://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers/wiki/Data-Source-DotNet).

Comment: Yes, I viewed Nibble's blog. The examples on it for Umbraco 7.x are based on AngularJS.
Thank you for introducing UComponents and NuPickers.

Comment: can you show me how can I generate custom property editors just using C# classes and class attributes in Umbraco 7.3 ?

Comment: Have you tried the older implementations like the charlimiteditor on his site? The methods are deprecated but that's not the same as obsolete so they might still work.  The easiest way for yourself might be to use nuPickers. I've updated my answers to reflect.